# XML (de)serialization invalid string inconsistent in c#?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, illegal-characters

In C# (.net 4.0 and 4.5 / vs2010 and vs12) when I serialize an object containing a string having an illegal character using XMLSerializer, no error is thrown. However, when I deserialize that result, an "invalid character" error is thrown.

```
        // add to XML
        Items items = new Items();
        items.Item = "\v hello world"; // contains "illegal" character \v

        // variables
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Items));
        string tmpFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

        // serialize
        using (FileStream tmpFileStream = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(tmpFileStream, items);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Success! XML serialized in file " + tmpFile);

        // deserialize
        Items result = null;
        using (FileStream plainTextFile = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            result = (Items)serializer.Deserialize(plainTextFile); //FAILS here
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.Item);
```

"Items" is just a small class autogenerated by xsd /c Items.xsd. Items.xsd is nothing more than a root element (Items) containing one child (Item):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Items">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The error thrown during deserialization is

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: There is an
>   error in XML document (3, 12). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: '♂',
>   hexadecimal value 0x0B, is an invalid character. Line 3, position 12.

The serialized XML file contains on line 3 this:

```
<Item>&#xB; hello world</Item>
```

I know \v -> & # xB; is an illegal character, but why does XMLSerialize allows it to be serialized (without error)? I find it inconsistent of .NET that it allows me to serialize something without a problem only to find out that I cannot deserialize it.

Is there a solution so either the XMLSerializer removes the illegal characters automatically before serializing or can I instruct the deserialization to ignore the illegal characters?

Currently I do solve it by reading the file contents as a string, replacing "manually" the illegal characters and next deserialize it... but I find that an ugly hack/work around.

Comment: you may need to check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899872/fast-way-to-deserialize-xml-with-special-characters

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### **1.**

You can set `XmlWriterSettings`'s `CheckCharacters` property to avoid writing illegal chars.(`Serialize` method would throw exception)

```
using (FileStream tmpFileStream = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    var writer = XmlWriter.Create(tmpFileStream, new XmlWriterSettings() { CheckCharacters = true});
    serializer.Serialize(writer, items);
}
```

### **2.**

You can create your own XmlTextWriter to filter out unwanted chars while serializing

```
using (FileStream tmpFileStream = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    var writer = new MyXmlWriter(tmpFileStream);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, items);
}

public class MyXmlWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public MyXmlWriter(Stream s) : base(s, Encoding.UTF8)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        string newText = String.Join("", text.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)));
        base.WriteString(newText);
    }
}
```

### **3.**

By creating your own XmlTextReader you can filter out unwanted chars while deserializing

```
using (FileStream plainTextFile = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var reader = new MyXmlReader(plainTextFile);
    result = (SomeObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
}

public class MyXmlReader : XmlTextReader
{
    public MyXmlReader(Stream s) : base(s)
    {
    }

    public override string ReadString()
    {
        string text =  base.ReadString();
        string newText = String.Join("", text.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)));
        return newText;
    }
}
```

### **4.**

You can set `XmlReaderSettings`'s `CheckCharacters` property to false. Deserialization will work now smoothly. (you'll get `\v` back.)

```
using (FileStream plainTextFile = new FileStream(tmpFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    var reader = XmlReader.Create(plainTextFile, new XmlReaderSettings() { CheckCharacters = false });
    result = (SomeObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader); 
}
```