# XmlReader buffer seems to ignore changes to the buffer?

Tags: c#, streamreader, xmlreader

Perhaps my understanding of what is supposed to happen is faulty, so hopefully someone can correct my thought process here.

I am trying to process many large XML files that are constantly being sent to us with bad characters embedded in the text (0x1A)... unfortunately, its our customer that is sending the files so no matter how nicely we ask them to make the files actually be valid XML, they consider it *our* problem.

Ultimately I wrote a subclass of `StreamReader` like so:

```
public class CleanTextReader : StreamReader
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;

    public CleanTextReader(Stream stream, ILog logger) : base(stream)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }

    public CleanTextReader(Stream stream) : this(stream, LogManager.GetLogger<CleanTextReader>())
    {
        //nothing to do here.
    }
    public override int Read(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            var rVal = base.Read(buffer, index, count);

            var filteredBuffer = buffer.Select(x => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(x) ? x : ' ').ToArray();

            Buffer.BlockCopy(filteredBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, count);
            return rVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.Error("Read(char[], int, int)", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public override int ReadBlock(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
    {
        try
        {
            var rVal = base.ReadBlock(buffer, index, count);
            var filteredBuffer = buffer.Select(x => XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(x) ? x : ' ').ToArray();
            Buffer.BlockCopy(filteredBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, count);
            return rVal;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.Error("ReadBlock(char[], in, int)", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public override string ReadToEnd()
    {
        var chars = new char[4096];
        int len;
        var sb = new StringBuilder(4096);
        while ((len = Read(chars, 0, chars.Length)) != 0)
        {
            sb.Append(chars, 0, len);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

... then I implement the `XmlReader` like so:

```
using (var theCleanser = new CleanTextReader(myStreamedInput))
using (var theReader = XmlReader.Create(theCleanser))
{
    ...
    // do stuff with theReader
}
```

I have a unit test like so:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CleanTextReaderCleans0X1A()
    {
        //arrange
        var originalString = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
        var badChars = new string(new[] {(char) 0x1a});
        var concatenated = originalString.Replace("jumped", badChars + "jumped" + badChars);

        //act
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(concatenated)))
        {
            using (var reader = new CleanTextReader(stream))
            {
                var newString = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim().Replace("  ", " ");
                //assert
                Assert.IsTrue(originalString.Equals(newString));
            }
        }
    }
```

...this passes.

but when I try to parse an XML file with a 0x1A character in it, I still get a `System.Xml.XmlException`: '', *hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character.  Line XX, position XX*

Digging deeper into the `CleanTextReader` I examine the `Read(char[], int, int)` method, as it seems to be being hit by the `XmlReader`.  The original `buffer` has the illegal characters, but the `filteredBuffer` does not, and after the `Buffer.BlockCopy()` is run, both the `buffer` and the `filteredBuffer` are devoid of special characters.

Also of note, I discovered that the line number and position reference not the first instance of an invalid character, but the *second*, so it sees the first and corrects it, but only once.

So I'm scratching my head here.  How does the `XmlReader` get the special characters?  Is it reading from the buffer before control returns from the method?  How do I fix this problem?

**UPDATE**

per request, here is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
"System.Xml.XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid character. Line 84, position 38.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText(Int32& startPos, Int32& endPos, Int32& outOrChars)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseText()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.ReadElementFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFrom(XmlReader reader)
   at MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel.Loader.<GetGroupEligibilityElements>d__2b.MoveNext() in c:\\Projects\\MyCompanyHealth\\MyCompany.Importers\\MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel\\MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel\\Loader.cs:line 138
   at MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel.Loader.<GetGroupEligibilities>d__18.MoveNext() in c:\\Projects\\MyCompanyHealth\\MyCompany.Importers\\MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel\\MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel\\Loader.cs:line 71
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel.Test.LoadingTests.GroupEligibilityFileWithBadCharactersProperlyCleansed() in c:\\Projects\\MyCompanyHealth\\MyCompany.Importers\\MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel\\MyCompany.Importers.GroupEligibilityModel.Test\\LoadingTests.cs:line 118"   string
```

Comment: Can you please include the call stack of the System.Xml.XmlException?

Comment: Also, I cannot reproduce your problem, please provide a minimalistic  example XML. Specify exactly which characters/bytes are in the file, for example by posting a snapshot from a hex editor.

Comment: @helb I added the stack trace, but the xml file is a little more worrisome, being customer data.  I'll see if I can make an xml file with the bad characters that fails.

Comment: I'm having a hard time associating the exception call stack with the code you posted. Which lines throws exactly?

Comment: I think the error is thrown when consuming a node using `var node = XNode.ReadFrom(theReader) as XElement;`  I thought that was less relevant since if the filter were working properly, this wouldn't blow up.

Comment: There is no XNode.ReadFrom() call in the code you posted...

Comment: No that happens outside this process.  That works perfectly fine if given valid xml.  The problem is it's still seeing the 0x1A, and it shouldn't be able to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86732/discussion-between-helb-and-jeremy-holovacs).

Comment: Have you tried a different encoding? It looks like you are expecting UTF-8, but that may not be what you are getting.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Have you tried the alternatives [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13450902/932418) I think 3rd one may work for you.

Comment: Did you test that your methods are actually being called? Do not derive from StreamReader, that's a hack. Derive from TextReader and wrap a StreamReader.

Comment: @Mohair the xml is UTF-8, so I don't think that's the problem.