# Deserialize xml special characters in the code

Tags: c#, xml

I want to deserialize special characters. This is the sample XML tag:

```
<Address1>125*1(&()*)1798</Address1>
```

How can I do that using `XmlSerializer`? I want to do this in the code in c# rather than changing the contents of the Xml because the file is being uploaded by the user. I can't ask the user to fix the contents in the XML. I want to rather handle this in C# code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what happens when you try to deserialize it using XmlSerializer?

Comment: @andrerpena: invalid characters at line XXX.

Comment: The `&` character  is one of five [XML reserved characters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145315%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), and must be escaped when part of a text literal, like so: `&amp;`.

Comment: Might be encoding related, some explanation here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899872/fast-way-to-deserialize-xml-with-special-characters